# C++11 async segmentation fault

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, c++11

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong here:

```
#include <future>
#include <iostream>


int main() {    
    std::future<int> result( std::async([](int m) { return m+1;}, 2));
    std::cout << "In main" << std::endl;
    std::cout << result.get();
}
```

With GCC 4.8 or 4.9, I get a segmentation fault.
    :

```
./a.out:


 In main
        Segmentation fault: 11



    : /opt/local/bin/g++-mp-4.8 -v
    Using built-in specs.
    COLLECT_GCC=/opt/local/bin/g++-mp-4.8
    COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/opt/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12/4.8.1/lto-wrapper
    Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12
    Configured with: ../gcc-4.8.1/configure --prefix=/opt/local --build=x86_64-apple-darwin12 --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,lto,fortran,java --libdir=/opt/local/lib/gcc48 --includedir=/opt/local/include/gcc48 --infodir=/opt/local/share/info --mandir=/opt/local/share/man --datarootdir=/opt/local/share/gcc-4.8 --with-local-prefix=/opt/local --with-system-zlib --disable-nls --program-suffix=-mp-4.8 --with-gxx-include-dir=/opt/local/include/gcc48/c++/ --with-gmp=/opt/local --with-mpfr=/opt/local --with-mpc=/opt/local --with-ppl=/opt/local --with-cloog=/opt/local --enable-cloog-backend=isl --disable-cloog-version-check --enable-stage1-checking --disable-multilib --enable-lto --enable-libstdcxx-time --with-as=/opt/local/bin/as --with-ld=/opt/local/bin/ld --with-ar=/opt/local/bin/ar --with-bugurl=https://trac.macports.org/newticket --with-pkgversion='MacPorts gcc48 4.8.1_0'
    Thread model: posix
    gcc version 4.8.1 (MacPorts gcc48 4.8.1_0)
```

Edit: Some people have pointed to another answer that says link with pthread. That does not solve the problem:

```
: /opt/local/bin/g++-mp-4.8 -std=c++11 -lpthread thread5.cc
: ./a.out
In main
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Comment: Did you link with `-pthread`?

Comment: [Seems to work on 4.8.1](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=f82d46302006f30b481f84cf831fb374-08d1f1279a7cb98460a995a1b0c84fe6).

Comment: With all due respect, this is not a duplicate. I did link with lpthread and it still crashes: $: /opt/local/bin/g++-mp-4.8 -std=c++11 -lpthread thread5.cc $./a.out
In main
Segmentation fault: 11

Comment: @duli, use the flag `-pthread` and not `-lpthread`.

Comment: Makes no difference: : /opt/local/bin/g++-mp-4.8 -std=c++11 -pthread thread5.cc : ./a.out
In main
Segmentation fault: 11

Comment: Build with debug symbols (use `-g`), run under a debugger, post the stack trace in your question. As @Praetorian shows, the rest of us are having difficulty reproducing this problem.

Comment: Works for me with g++, but fails with clang++.

Comment: Make sure a.out finds the right libraries (check with `ldd`).

Comment: Yes - the problem is that even when I compile with -pthread or -lpthread, I do not get the library: otool -L a.out
a.out:
 /opt/local/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.19.0)
 /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 169.3.0)
 /opt/local/lib/gcc48/libgcc_s.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)

Comment: I can't get this to crash, built with gcc 4.7.2 on cygwin.

Comment: What code is it executing when it segfaults?  Break out `gdb`.

Comment: same with  Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0
Thread model: posix
using  cmake CXX 20

Answer (score 0):

I've tested the code with clang 3.2(apple llvm 4.2) and it runs just fine. it returns

```
In main
3
```

**edit:**
Also other people tested with gcc 4.8.1 and it works. The most probable issue is that you are linking to the default pthread library instead of the one that comes with gcc 4.8.1 from macports